# std::multiset and finding the middle element

Tags: c++, stl

I have `std::multiset` which If i iterate over from `std::multiset::begin()` to `std::multiset::end()` i will get sorted elements. How Do I get the middle element in this `std::multiset` other than iterating from `std::multiset::begin()` to `std::multiset::begin() + size() / 2`

Comment: There's no other way, unless you know in advance what the middle element is, or you use a different data structure.

Comment: It is possible, but non portable solution with hacking of encapsulation. E.g. gcc std::multiset<> uses _Rb_tree where _M_begin() just points on the middle of set. But _Rb_tree implementation is private - so you must hack this encapsulation with reinterpret_cast<> or sth other and this _Rb_tree implementation detail is just what gcc uses now - we can't be sure it will be portable even within various versions of gcc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a solution to get median value for std::multiset:

```
template<class T>
double GetMedian(const std::multiset<T>& data)
{
    if (data.empty())
        throw std::length_error("Cannot calculate median value for empty dataset");

    const size_t n = data.size();
    double median = 0;

    auto iter = data.cbegin();
    std::advance(iter, n / 2);

    // Middle or average of two middle values
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        const auto iter2 = iter--;
        median = double(*iter + *iter2) / 2;    // data[n/2 - 1] AND data[n/2]
    }
    else
    {
        median = *iter;
    }

    return median;
}
```

And if you need median absolute deviation (mdev) for example:

```
template<class T>
double GetMedianAbsoluteDeviation(const std::multiset<T>& data)
{
    const double fMedian = GetMedian(data);
    std::multiset<double> diff;
    for (const auto& x : data)
    {
        diff.insert(std::abs(fMedian - x));
    }
    return GetMedian(diff);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated text part of my comment. Code is unchanged.

Comment: A minor point that this function will return 0 in cases where it should probably throw an exception, like in the case where data is empty.  0 might be a completely reasonable return value for a set of data that is centered around 0.

Comment: Thanks! If improved the code by adding throw std::length_error()

Comment: How is this any different that just iter++ ? This does not address the runtime issue with getting the median without iterating over each elements in the set. I just wrote up a blog post for a multiset wrapper that does some this problem with O(1) access to the median value. See https://medium.com/programming-in-the-wild/log-n-sorted-container-in-c-22446b64e2bc