# How to access particular element in a multiset in c++?

Tags: c++, stl, multiset

I wanted to find the median of a continuous stream of input and display it as values are input. I thought of using a multiset for this purpose as it will keep the input values sorted.

using an iterator I am trying to find the median element which is the mid

```
multiset <int> s;
multiset <int> :: iterator it;

it = s.begin() + s.size()/2;

cout<<(*it)<<endl;
```

But this gives me an error!

Is there not any way of accessing just one element from a multiset ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140635/stdmultiset-and-finding-the-middle-element

Comment: `But this gives me an error!` When asking questions like this, you should include the actual error you received. But I suspect, that the error is due to the fact, that set iterators doesn't have `operator+` defined for them. The typical use case for sets is to check for presence of elements in them, so you aren't using it as intended.

Comment: Yup! advance() worked! Thanks a lot ! :D